# How to resolve an access denied exception in Artificatory

Tags: maven, maven-2, artifactory, bamboo

I have a problem while accessing a file from Artifcatory.

I have a **local maven repository** in Atifactory. The repository name is **test** and this repository contains jar files.

I am using **bamboo**(build tool) to deploy the files into the another repository called **test1**, while deploying I have a jar dependency which is placed in the repository **test**, when I try to access/download the jar from the test repository location I am getting access denied exception (unauthorised, ReasonPhrase:Forbidden) error in bamboo.

But if I use the same credential in my local machine .m2(settings.xml) I am able to access/download the file/jar from the Artifactory test.

**FYI:**

1. User Permission: The user has read, deploy and delete permission.
2. User has the above permission to the **test** repository
3. Accessing the URL through Browser with same credential : Was able to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Bamboo+Artifactory+Plug-in#BambooArtifactoryPlug-in-TheArtifactoryGenericResolveTask) on Bamboo Artifactory integration. Access denied is due to the unauthorised request, can you confirm if the username and password is passed when Artifactory was initially setup with Bamboo? Also, you can pass on the credentials in the resolver task itself in the resolvere username and resolver password as below,
[image]

Comment: We have not setup/integrated the artifactory in the bamboo, we are using maven plugin(maven 3.3.9) for the build/deployment. The credentials are read from bamboo's settings.xml file and jfrog url from the pom.xml file.

Comment: it seems to be that the setting.xml's credentials cannot be read properly or check if bamboo can connect to the Artifactory. I would recommend to use the Artifactory bamboo plugin and perform the same using the provided tasks.

Comment: The credentials are read properly I believe, because before downloading the file from test repo, we are successfully downloading the other dependencies from other  repositories.